# Ruby String Integer Scanning

Tags: ruby, string, parsing

Is there a Ruby equivalent of the Java Scanner?

If I have a string like "hello 123 hi 234"

In Java I could do

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("hello 123 hi 234");
String a = sc.nextString();
int b = sc.nextInt();
String c = sc.nextString();
int d = sc.nextInt();
```

How would you do this in Ruby?

Comment: This sounds like a half-step. In Ruby, half-steps tend to disappear completely. What do you -want- to do ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multiple assignment from arrays can be useful for this

```
a,b,c,d = sc.split
b=b.to_i
d=d.to_i
```

A less efficient alternative:

```
a,b,c,d = sc.split.map{|w| Integer(w) rescue w}
```

Comment: That would be total genius if Ruby could determine a and c were strings and b and d were integers. Still close enough for me to have learnt something!

Comment: In the Java example, the programmer has to know which words are expected to be integers, so there's nothing wrong with a Ruby solution relying upon that requirement.  And this -is- prettier than either of my solutions.

Comment: @Pongus: The question *already* specifies that `a` and `c` are strings and `b` and `d` are integers, so what's wrong with relying on that?

Comment: Wow.  That one-liner is just elegant.  +1 from me.

Comment: @Jörg: I didnt mean for it to sound like I was complaining, I would have just been doubly impressed if Ruby had worked that out for us. Still +1. Would have been +2 since the edit if I could. :-)

Comment: I'll upvote if you change 'not as performant' to 'less efficient'

Comment: An integer-detecting version that doesn't rely on exceptions (possibly faster — haven't profiled): `a,b,c,d = sc.split.map {|w| w.empty? || w =~ /\D/ ? w : w.to_i}`

Comment: @chuck - depends on the density of integers

Answer (score 12):

Use `String.scan`:

```
>> s = "hello 123 hi 234"
=> "hello 123 hi 234"
>> s.scan(/\d+/).map{|i| i.to_i}
=> [123, 234]
```

RDoc [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000812)

If you want something closer to the Java implementation, you can use [StringScanner](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/StringScanner.html):

```
>> require 'strscan'
 => true
>> s = StringScanner.new "hello 123 hi 234"
=> # < StringScanner 0/16 @ "hello...">
>> s.scan(/\w+/)
=> "hello"
>> s.scan(/\s+/)
=> " "
>> s.scan(/\d+/)
=> "123"
>> s.scan_until(/\w+/)
=> " hi"
>> s.scan_until(/\d+/)
=> " 234"
```